# Mobx-React store property undefined on first render, but async loading variable passes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm managing my state using Mobx. I call an action for an http request to load pictures, then update the pictures property, then update the loading property. When I load the component that makes the call and console.log the store properties, the loading property is updated, but the picture property is still undefined. It's not until the second render of the component that the picture property is defined Here's an example:

```
export class PhotoStore {
@observable picInfo = []
@observable loading = true

@action loadPics() {
this.loading = true;
let dataURL = 'some url';
return axios.get(dataURL)
.then(res => {this.picInfo = res.data})
.then(this.loading = false)
}

class PhotoGallery extends React.Component{
 componentWillMount(){
  this.PhotoStore.loadPics();
}
 render(){
console.log(//these two properties)
//returns false and undefined object
  return(
//some code
 );
}

}
```

I know I can just check for the picInfo.length before rendering the JSX, but I want to make this work. Thanks for any tips in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the second .then clause.  When you set this.picInfo, also set this.loading.  Because you put the loading state change in a chained promise, there is a timing issue where the @observable tries to evaluate before the loading is set.

Answer (score 0):

https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html - see `runInAction` and the `asyncAction` decorator

```
@action loadPics() {
  this.loading = true;
  let dataURL = 'some url';
  return axios.get(dataURL)
    .then(res => {runInAction(() => {this.picInfo = res.data})}
    .then(runInAction(() =>this.loading = false))
}
```